How do I list divs in rows from columns using flexbox without overgrowing the div?
I'm trying to make a responsive list that goes from horizontal to vertical using a media query. The problem I found is that I don't know how to properly display does item inline without making the div overgrow to fit all the cards.
I've been using the flexbox for the whole page, this is the HTML. I've also tried using a wrapper but still not got anything from it besides the issue I'm facing


body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* colonne */

.column {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    margin: 2rem;
}

#column-1 {
    flex-grow: 4;
    min-width: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#column-2 {
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: scroll;
}

/* righe */

.row {
    display: flex;
}

#row-1 {
    min-height: 40px;
    flex-grow: 0.1;
    background-color: brown;
}

#row-2 {
    flex-grow: 0.8;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#row-3 {
    flex-grow: 0.1;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #row-2 {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    #column-1 {
        height: 40vh;
        /* Adjust height as needed */
        min-height: 300px;
    }

    #column-2 {
        height: 10vh;
        /* Adjust height as needed */
        min-height: 100px;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

}
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row" id="row-1"></div>

        <div class="row" id="row-2">
            <div class="column" id="column-1">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column" id="column-2">
             
            
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="cardColumn"></div>
                        <div class="cardColumn">
                            <div class="cardRow"></div>
                            <div class="cardRow"></div>
                            <div class="cardRow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                            <!--Other Cards here-->

              </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="row-3"></div>

    </div>
</body>



And the relative CodePen

There are 2 main problems here. One is that you are allowing your container to expand too much because you are using flex-grow. To fix that you can try to add
overflow: hidden or set max dimensions by parent using %. The other problem is that when width is less than 800px you are setting flex-direction: column for row, but it still has flex-wrap: wrap, so it actually puts everything in one line, since it would not fit vertically.
So to make it work:
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #row-2 {
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: unset;
    }
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}


thank you very much that was really clear. I feel dumb now but I guess I'm closer to get the Ah-Ha Moment people is telling me about.
